# Python.Implement a function to parse a string containing data in text format.Return the result as a dictionary

Tags: python

can you please help, my code solves only part of the tasks correctly and I can't understand why. He parses the first two examples correctly, but he does not deal with other examples, for example,
with this example: `([ loc @"lage_187" to q(veinan_824);], [ loc @"axedi_678" tonq(eddior_950); ], [loc @"zadies_990"to q(arxe_507);], [ loc @"usve_8"nto q(bixeed_984); ], )` ,
he does not deal with.  Here is the task and my code.

> Implement a function to parse a string containing data in text format. Explore the details of the format using the examples below. Return the result as a dictionary.

> Example 1
>
> Input string: `( [ loc @"edre"to q(isin_233);], [ loc @"bizaza" to q(ria_972); ], )`
>
> Disassembled result: `{'isin_233': 'edre', 'ria_972': 'bizaza'}`
>
> Example 2
>
> Input string: `([ loc @"lage_187" to q(veinan_824);], [ loc @"axedi_678" toq(eddior_950); ], [loc @"zadies_990"to q(arxe_507);], [ loc @"usve_8"to q(bixeed_984); ], )`
>
> Disassembled result: `{'veinan_824': 'lage_187','eddior_950': 'axedi_678','arxe_507': 'zadies_990','bixeed_984': 'usve_8'}`

```py
def main(s):
    d = {}
    elements = s.strip()[3:-3].split('], [')
    for elem in elements:
        loc, _, q = elem.strip().partition('to q(')
        loc = loc.strip()[6:-1]
        q = q[:-2].strip()
        if not q:
            continue
        if "\n" in q:
            q1, q2 = q.split("\n")
            q1 = q1.rstrip(");")
            q2 = q2.rstrip(");")
            q1 = q1[q1.rfind("(") + 1:]
            q2 = q2[q2.rfind("(") + 1:]
            d[q1] = loc.replace('@', '').replace('"', '')
            d[q2] = loc.replace('@', '').replace('"', '')
        else:
            q = q.rstrip(");")
            q = q[q.rfind("(") + 1:]
            d[q] = loc.replace('@', '').replace('"', '')
    return d
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "does not deal with"?

Comment: `split('], [')` removes the brackets between elements, but not the initial `([` or the ending `, ])`.

Comment: @ScottHunter, for the third example , the code outputs :
 {'veinan_824': 'lage_187', 'arxe_507': 'zadies_990', 'bixeed_984': 'usve_8'} .  
But a correctly parsed answer: 
{'veinan_824': 'lage_187', 'eddior_950': 'axedi_678', 'arxe_507': 'zadies_990', 'bixeed_984': 'usve_8'}

Comment: No, it shouldn't, as `to q(` doesn't appear in the `eddior_950` element.  At least that's what your code says.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex solution that pulls out strings in the form of `@"..."` and `q(...)`. It converts the result of `re.findall` to a dictionary and while it's doing that it reverses the order of the strings.

```
import re

def parse(s):
    return dict((p[1],p[0]) for p in re.findall(r'@"([^"]*)"[^q]+q\(([^)]*)', s))
```

Test run:

```
>>> parse('( [ loc @"edre"to q(isin_233);], [ loc @"bizaza" to q(ria_972); ], )')
{'isin_233': 'edre', 'ria_972': 'bizaza'}
>>> parse('([ loc @"lage_187" to q(veinan_824);], [ loc @"axedi_678" tonq(eddior_950); ], [loc @"zadies_990"to q(arxe_507);], [ loc @"usve_8"nto q(bixeed_984); ], )')
{'veinan_824': 'lage_187', 'eddior_950': 'axedi_678', 'arxe_507': 'zadies_990', 'bixeed_984': 'usve_8'}
```

There's probably a better regex, but this seems to work.

Regex explanation.

| Code | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| @" | Literal: **@"** |
| ([^"]*) | Capture all following chars up to a **"** |
| " | Literal: **"** |
| [^q]+ | Skip all chars up to a **q** |
| q\( | Literal: **q(** |
| ([^)]*) | Capture all following chars up to a **)** |